# Ubuntu 16.04 memory full due to /var/log/cups/error_log

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

After recently updating from 14.04 to 16.04, I tried to update to 18.04. However, when I try to do this, it keeps on failing presumably because of no disk space. When I click "Properties" on the "Computer" tab in "Files", it says that I have absolutely no free disk space, which I found strange because I transferred 40GB to a hard disk just before trying to update to 18.04 for the first time. I only just realized that memory could be a problem, but till now, I have tried to update to 18.04 multiple times.

When I do `dpkg -l linux-headers-\* linux-image-\* | grep ^ii`, I get the following, probably because I tried to update to 18.04 a lot of times:

```
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-141             4.4.0-141.167        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic     4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-142             4.4.0-142.168        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic     4.4.0-142.168        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic               4.4.0.142.148        amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic       3.16.0-43.58~14.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic       4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic       4.4.0-142.168        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic 3.16.0-43.58~14.04.1 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic 4.4.0-141.167        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic 4.4.0-142.168        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 4.4.0.142.148        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Is the existence of so many images and headers causing the memory full issue? If yes, how do I delete the proper ones?

The cause for the memory full issue is that my `/var/log/cups/error_log` is 86GB! Can I just delete this or is there a better and safer solution?

Comment: Read the log and solve the recurring CUPS error first.

Comment: See [space on disk running low error log...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836154/space-on-disk-running-low-error-logging-var-log-cups-error-log)